# How can I flow data from Power Bi into my Data pipeline?

Tags: javascript, python, powerbi

Quick overview of my project. The company I work for uses Power Bi for data analysis. We convey some of that data in dashboards, but some of it gets imported into excel workbooks. These workbooks require a considerable amount of time to refresh for our clients since it requires opening each one up and refreshing, and then checking data sources and such.
I'm working on automating this process and so far I have created a javascript funciton that uses SheetJS to combine a template workbook in sharepoint with a workbook that has the data in sharepoint, then uploaded that back to the folder we store reports in. The final key to the puzzle is losing that data workbook and directly pulling that data from Power Bi. Our system consists of JS and python, so if there's a way to do that in either language I can make it work. I have spent the last couple weeks trying to find a way to duplicate the olap connection that excel uses to query Power Bi, but have not found any packages or information that was helpful. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The best direction would to be to access the source and not go through Power BI and Excel, get the data into a format for you analysis from there. Power BI is not a suitable extraction layer, it is designed for analysis, not large query dumps

Comment: Problem with that is we have so many tables working together. We would have to rebuild all those relationships again with sql queries, which is what we are trying to avoid. I know this is possible because this company offers it: https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/create-pivot-table-with-olap-data-javascript.aspx. This seems to be a similar query to what Excel uses to connect, but the price tag is too much just for needing this one capability they offer.